# Accessing useReducer state in an action creator

Tags: reactjs

Let’s say I don’t use Redux (and therefore no Redux Thunk involved) in my application, and instead, I manage my state with the useReducer hook.

The issue is that in the action creator, I want to access the state itself. Does the only solution is to give the state itself as a parameter to the action creator, or is there a way to get the same benefits of the Redux Thunk, and be able to access the state itself through some getState() function?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet for this question? I’m facing the same issue by trying to getState in action.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reducer that accepts state & action and returns a new state based on the action (same as redux).
When you are calling 'useReducer' you should pass it the reducer you've built and the initial state.
You will get back the state and dispatcher (the function that will use you to update the state - same as redux).

Please find the following articles explain how to achieve it shortly and simply:
https://www.peanutbutterjavascript.com/roll-your-own-redux-with-usecontext-usereducer/?fbclid=IwAR2je-sa5UW_5elE8UlkcUfZEzYjiwBO44P4smsn3NPznUiMS3EZEKsILEw

https://medium.com/@martin.crabtree/react-creating-a-redux-like-global-state-with-the-usecontext-and-usereducer-hooks-89aa2b27dbc5